# how to Install global mouse Hook for certain UI like "desktop"

Tags: c#, hook, mouse-hook

the code so far installs a hook to detect the mouse activity but what i want is either to filter the activity for certain UI **or** to detect where the clicks has occurred (on which hwnd ) exactly '**Desktop**'
is there a way ?

this is the code i've used it's from Microsoft website 
here  : [How to set a Windows hook in Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318804)

EDIT : i found that he code provided by is not global so for global hook check link in the answer the answer ,,

Comment: You pretty much have to know the HWND first then do your own filtering during your global callback.  Use `GetDesktopWindow ()` to get HWND of Desktop ahead of time

Comment: thank you @Micky for your reply i already thought about using 'GetDesktioWindow()' to get the HWND but **where or how can i filter it during global callback ?** 
"first i tried to use 'WndProc()' but i found out it only receives messages passed to HWND i am using and nothing about desktop "

Comment: No worries, as per the example install a WH_MOUSE and the HWND will be in the `MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT.hwnd` via the LPARAM of your `MouseHook()` callback

Comment: i found that this hook is not global and only works within the form am using  it was so depressing for me
should i edit the question ? i have to start from zero calling WH_MOUSE_LL instead Of WH_MOUSE

Comment: Perhaps it's a limitation of .NET?  Up to you.  I always did global hooks from c/c++.  Wishing you well

Comment: Dear @MickyDuncan i found that WH_MOUSE_LL struct have no HWND in it and the  WH_MOUSE stuct (which is not global) have HWND that "according to Microsoft website :"
hwnd
Type: HWND
A handle to the window that will receive the mouse message corresponding to the mouse event.
what do you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First about the hook i found that  it's not global and i found open-source global hook [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) so whenever the mouse click occurs an event will fire and there i run simple callback code that checks if the desktop is the active control

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetClassName(int hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

public void GetActiveWindow() {
const int maxChars = 256;
int handle = 0;
StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(maxChars);

handle = GetForegroundWindow();

if (GetClassName(handle, className, maxChars) > 0) {
    string cName = className.ToString();
    if (cName == "Progman" || cName == "WorkerW") {
        // desktop is active
    } else {
        // desktop is not active
    }
}
```

}

**DONE**!

special thanks to Micky Duncaand and AJKenny84